# How to setup the DfxParser in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, import

I want to use https://github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser in my project. When i import in like:

```
import { DxfParser } from 'dxf-parser';
```

and than call:

```
new DxfParser()
```

i get an error:

> TypeError: dxf_parser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a
>   constructor

What would be the correct way to use the DxfParser in angular? I want to do the same in angular as the jaascript example on projects site:

```
var parser = new DxfParser(); 
try {
 var dxf = parser.parseSync(fileText); 
}catch(err) {
 return console.error(err.stack); 
}
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the readme of the github states, did you install DxfParser?

```
npm install dxf-parser
```

You might also need to install the types for typescript like so:

```
npm install @types/dxf-parser
```

Since installing does not seem to be the problem I tried it myself. Doing the import like you did does not work. I looked into the code and it seems that DxfParser is a default export. So if you do:

```
import DxfParser from "dxf-parser";
```

It should be working.

[More information on exports can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

Comment: i installed dxf-parser, there are no types available:
"Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fdxf-parser - Not found"

Comment: @george I have updated the answer. Does this help you?

Comment: i thought i tried that too, i event started to defined my own types and that didn't work out, but your code works. thx!

Comment: an additional question, i go further and wanna use three-dxf. 
My import statement is  "import ThreeDxf from 'three-dxf'"
When i call 
cadCanvas = new ThreeDxf.Viewer(dxf, document.getElementById('cad-view'), 400, 400);
i get an error "TypeError: three_dxf__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.Viewer is not a constructor"

in Javascript its defined as:

var ThreeDxf;
(function(ThreeDxf) {
ThreeDxf.Viewer = function(data, parent, width, height, font) {
.........

Comment: @george Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for this. I suggest you create a new question on SO, sorry :/

Comment: i refactored it to a class ThreeDxfViewer similiar to DxfParser and now i can import it in angular

Comment: @george can you share the refactored class as i am facing same issue in react

Comment: i dont have it anymore and more important i solved it by configuration, if i remember correctly, cos now i can just do 
`import { DxfParser } from 'dxf-parser';
....
const parser = new DxfParser();
const dxf = parser.parseSync(file);
....`

must be some settings in tsconfig.json or angular.json. If i find it, i'll let u know